# How to view class structure, including inherited fields, in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

Is it possible to view all the methods and fields of a class, including inherited fields?

Something similar to the structure view but include all symbols.

Currently, I type `this.` and see all the suggestions.

Comment: [`RIDER-50387` - Show inherited members in Structure view](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-50387/Show-inherited-members-in-Structure-view)

Answer (score 5):

Does the [File Member](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File_Member.html) command (<kbd>Alt+\</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd>) help you? It contains the inherited fields as well:
[image: screenshot - File Member popup]

Comment: in order for it to get the effect I was searching for i had to check the option 'include members from related files'. The meaning of this option is a bit ambiguous but it looks promising

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Would be nice if there was an option to "stick" this `File Member` menu in the text editor so it's always visible (kind of like in VS with a visible dropdown menu). BTW it seems the `CTRL + F12` shortcut has been removed for this feature. It's only `ALT + \` now